# Two instances with the same memory address

Tags: objective-c

For an instance of NSObject, I want to use the hash to be its unique identity. But I soon find out that sometimes I create two instances with the same address which leads to the same hash , look at the code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"new iCMMessageHomeViewController: %@", self);

}
```

then I push and pop several times with this ViewController, the log is like this:

```
2018-06-05 15:21:14.167585+0800 iCityCQ[11685:4240006] new iCMMessageHomeViewController: <iCMMessageHomeViewController: 0x109f41080>
......

2018-06-05 15:21:17.861901+0800 iCityCQ[11685:4240006] new iCMMessageHomeViewController: <iCMMessageHomeViewController: 0x109f41080>
```

I am sure that the first instance has been dealloced when popped.

My intuition tells me that this should happen really rarely. Does this means that it is easy to create two instances of the same object with the same address?

Comment: What's the code how you create iCMMessageHomeViewController ?

Comment: Memory is reused. How easy was it to see two view controllers with the same address? Is a hash unique?

Comment: @Willeke   push and pop about one to five times. As the address is the same so that the same hash.

Comment: @battlmonstr iCMMessageHomeViewController *VC = [[iCMMessageHomeViewController alloc] init]; then push the vc onto navigationController.

Comment: Do you maybe override "init" (or one of init methods) in some way?

Comment: Conclusions: When an object is released, its memory can be reused by an object of the same class. A hash is not unique, read about hash tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a unique value, use NSUUID.   You can create an `@property` on your class with name `uniqueIentifier` that returns the NSUUID that you (likely) generate when an instance was created.   The property should be readonly.